# How to make HttpRequest object case-sensitive

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, collections, httprequest, namevaluecollection

I am working on asp .net web project, In which i am stuck in architectural issue.

I having two Request parameters with same key but they are Case sensitive.

```
Param names =>  reportDate and ReportDate
```

As we know Request object internally implements NameValueCollection for it parameters, which is not case sensitive.

So above two parameters values will merged in a single a value with comma separated.

Which i don't want.

How can i overcome this problem.

Can i write my custom Request module where i can specify IEquality comparator for name-value collection.
Because i don't want to change much of code.

Any suggestion from any one is ?

Thanks in advance.